# Selenium: Check if element exist i loop, if true, click, if not continue

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to solve a issue which I cant wrap my head around whats the best solution for Selenium.

I want to check if a element exist and is displayed. If it is, click it and close it and continue with the rest of the code code. I want evaluate this for each loop to go through my list.

Example/pseudo code as of now:

...

```
for i in (urlList):
    browser.get(i)
    if #element exist and is displayed (//div[contains(@class,'wizard-tooltip-btn skip'))
       # Find it and click/close it (browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'wizard-tooltip-btn skip')]").click())
    else:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@data-name='data-window']").click()
    title_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('pane-legend-title__description')
    ticker = browser.find_element_by_class_name('chart-data-window-header')
    tickerClean = ticker.text.split(',')[0]
    latestClose = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]')
    latestBase = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[9]/div[2]/span')
    data.append(title_element.text + ',' + tickerClean + ',' + latestBase.text + ',' + latestClose.text)
    print('Done' + title_element.text + ',' + tickerClean + ',' + latestBase.text + ',' + latestClose.text)
```

...

Comment: I use WATIR where it's possible but in selenium it's not possible if you use implicit wait. Infact it's possible but it wouldn't move as you expected because you would be locked up by implicit wait when you check whether element exist. Since WATIR has its own timer and also it wouldn't be using the driver level wait, it's exactly possible as you are asking, you can simply check `b.element.exist?` or `b.element.present?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap the `.click()` in a ***try, catch*** statement. This way you can try and click the element every loop, but catch the exception that is thrown when it's **not present/visible**.

> NOTE: If you are using **Implicit Waits**, each element check will take
>   however many seconds you have set the Implicit Wait to. I would not
>   recommend using Implicit, and use **Explicit Waits** instead in your
>   Selenium scripts. [HERE](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) you will find the docs on both.

Here is an example using your example:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException

for i in (urlList):
    browser.get(i)
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'wizard-tooltip-btn skip')]").click()
    except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException):
        pass
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@data-name='data-window']").click()
    title_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('pane-legend-title__description')
    ticker = browser.find_element_by_class_name('chart-data-window-header')
    tickerClean = ticker.text.split(',')[0]
    latestClose = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]')
    latestBase = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[9]/div[2]/span')
    data.append(title_element.text + ',' + tickerClean + ',' + latestBase.text + ',' + latestClose.text)
    print('Done' + title_element.text + ',' + tickerClean + ',' + latestBase.text + ',' + latestClose.text)
```

If you are against the **try, catch** method, and would rather not deal with catching exceptions, you can use `find_elements` to **Truthy check** the existence of the element in a list, and click it if it passes, like this:

```
for i in (urlList):
    browser.get(i)
    if browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'wizard-tooltip-btn skip')]"):
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'wizard-tooltip-btn skip')]").click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@data-name='data-window']").click()
    title_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('pane-legend-title__description')
    ticker = browser.find_element_by_class_name('chart-data-window-header')
    tickerClean = ticker.text.split(',')[0]
    latestClose = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]')
    latestBase = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[9]/div[2]/span')
    data.append(title_element.text + ',' + tickerClean + ',' + latestBase.text + ',' + latestClose.text)
    print('Done' + title_element.text + ',' + tickerClean + ',' + latestBase.text + ',' + latestClose.text)
```

I could not tell by the wording of the question, but if you did ***not*** want to run the rest of the statements in the loop after you found and clicked the element, add a `continue` after it passes to whichever example you chose, as such:

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'wizard-tooltip-btn skip')]").click()
    continue
except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException):
    pass
```

or:

```
if browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'wizard-tooltip-btn skip')]"):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'wizard-tooltip-btn skip')]").click()
    continue
```

The `continue` will go to the next item in the loop without running the statements after the click.

Comment: This doesn't move as you expected, you will be caught up with implicit wait.

Comment: Only if you are setting the `implicitwait` to more than `0`, which is the default. I will put in a note to be aware of this.

Comment: They can't use explicit wait for every line of code,so implicit wait is the best . But we need to face these consequences as a result of using implicit wait.

Comment: You only need to ***wait*** for an element to exist if the *load* of the element is outside the *pageload*, using dynamic events like *AJAX*. In this case I would strong recommend using `Explicit` wait events for every load. I do not use Implicit and have thousands of lines of code written using selenium, so you ***can*** use `WebDriverWait` for every element that requires it.

Comment: Anyhow I am not facing this problem because I use WATIR which sits on the top of selenium which doesn't uses this driver level wait, it has the explicit kind of wait at the core.  So I can check like b.element.exists? And at the same time I wouldn't be loosing the waiting for element to exist and element to visible. Only when we automate very stable product we use seleniuim directly.